# Smoke and flame show in 3d vieport but are not rendered on v. 2.9

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, fire

I'm using 2.83.5 and trying 2.90. I followed a flamethrower tutorial recently and everything seemed to be going swimmingly until it came to rendering the fruits of my labour. While the bake went perfectly and I could see the results in the workflow screen when it came to rendering I got nothing except the scene.? I have included two images of the same. Any help here gratefully received. Below, the same two frames, the post bake workbench and the subsequent rendered result of the same frame: [image][image]

---

I guys. Having followed the advice of Paramesh, below the result. I reckon I must be having a brain fart or something. BTW this is CPU render in 2.83.5.

[image: Work room after bake (frame50)]
[image: Shader applied]
[image: Render result (frame 50)]

Any advice greatly received.

Merv

Comment: Can you share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com?